# how to create a sub section in posts

Tags: posts, permalinks, hacks

i need to create multiple section in my post.

for eg: i have a wordpress post called football with the perma: http://mysite.com/football

football contains sub section like rules/schedule/players/stadiums

Which should be like

http://mysite.com/football/rules

http://mysite.com/football/schedule

http://mysite.com/football/players

http://mysite.com/football/stadiums

when i click the main post football, it should redirect to /rules and should have the other links to navigate. just like the one in wordpress plugins [link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/order-up-custom-post-order/), is their any plugins to do or any snippets would be handy for me..

Comment: Why not use [anchors with an id attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i can think of is to create tabs, so try [**`WordPress Post Tabs`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs/)

> a plugin for WordPress that will help you add as many tabs to your
>   WordPress post or Page.